# How to ask sub questions in google docs

Tags: google-docs, formatting, google-docs-template

I have already searched the internet for this but I'm getting solutions for only google forms and not google docs. I'm trying to create a simple MCQ paper that looks like this...

> 1. Question one 
>    a. opt-1 
>    b. opt-2 
>    c. opt-3 
>    d. opt-4

How do I do this in google docs ?

I've tried using the numbered list but I'm only getting the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4..... but not sub divisions like 1. a, b, c...

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The feature that you are looking for is called numbered list. Please read the corresponding official help article: [Add a numbered list, bulleted list, or checklist](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3300615?hl=en). If you need further help, please show what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you type the question and press `Enter`, you are presented with the next number in the list. At this point, press the `Tab` key to indent and the value for that line will change to "a". Continue through all the options for that question; each new line will be the next letter of the alphabet.

When you have finished a question (and its options), and you press "Enter", and you are presented with the next letter in the sequence, then press `Shift-Tab` - the tab position will revert to the "number" position, and the value till change to the next number in the sequence.

If you'd like to put a blank line between questions, then you will need to press `Enter` to create the new line though this stops the "Numbered list". To create a new question, select the "Numbered list" as usual - the value will be the number one, regardless of the previous number in the sequence. To advance the number to the next in the sequence, right click and select "Continue previous numbering".